# Check for occurences of string in other string

Tags: code-golf, string

## Challenge

I'm sure you read the title, and came in to farm your rep, thinking its kids' stuff, but think again! You have to challenge each other in the *shortest* code to count the occurences of a string in another. For example, given the following input:

> aaaabbbbsssffhd

as a string, and the string

> s

should output

> 3

## Rules

Just before you smile and say, "Hey, I'll use ----," read this:

- No use of external libraries, or your language's API. You have to implement it manually. Which means you can't use your language's built-in function or method for counting occurences
- No file I/O
- No connecting with a server, website, et cetera
- In a case of `ababa`, where it starts with `aba` and if you read the last 3 letters it's also `aba`, you only count one*****

*Thank you @ProgramFOX for that (the last rule)!*

***Hint**: When you count occurences, you can remove the ones you counted to avoid disobeying this rule

I think the last 2 rules are just for rule benders!

## Winning Criterion

As previously stated the winner is the code with the less bytes used. The winner will be announced five days later (15 June 2014)

## My Small Answer

Here's my C++ answer, where it assumes that the `li` variable holds the string to check occurences in, and `l` is the string to look for in `f`:

#### Ungolfed

```
int c = 0;
while (li.find(lf) != string::npos)
{
    int p = li.find(lf);
    int l = p + lf.length() - 1;
    for (p = p; p <= l; p++)
    {
        li[p] = static_cast<char>(8);
    }
    ++c;
}
```

Of course, to use `std::string`, you have to include the string header file!

#### Golfed

```
int c=0;while(li.find(lf)!=string::npos){int p=li.find(lf);int l=p+lf.length()-1;for(p=p;p<=l;p++){li[p]=static_cast<char>(8);}++c;}
```

#### Result

The variable `c` is going to be the value of how many times the string was found

---

#### Enjoy!

## Winner

After a long wait [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/31507/19785) answer wins with only 3 bytes, written in GolfScript

Comment: Should we count the same character twice? For example, if the input is `ababa` and `aba`, should we output `1` or `2`? The third `a` is both the end of the first `aba` and the begin of the second `aba`.

Comment: Does language's API mean libraries that can be imported (that come with the language) or methods of builtin datatypes or commands themselves?

Comment: Does it need to deal with strings longer than `s` for matching? If not: I have a 5 char J solution: `+/a=b`

Comment: Does input come through variables or STDIN?

Comment: @ProgramFOX Sorry, forgot to out that in... You should output `1`. Thanks for the pointers!

Comment: @Synthetica To your utter dismay, it should be able to handle almost any string length ;)

Comment: @TheRare It is not specified, use what you want, but don't add the bytes used by input in calculating total bytes...

Comment: @TheRare What I mean is if your language has a built-in method or function for this purpose, you are not permitted to use it. The whole point is writing your own, in the *shortest* code...

Comment: Edit all that info in and I'll give you a +1.

Comment: Function or program?

Comment: @KyleKanos Well, this challenge is a lot more free than others: you choose!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## GolfScript, 3 bytes

```
/,(
```

Assumes string and substring are on the stack.

[Try it online.](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=ImFhYWFiYmJic3NzZmZoZCIicyIvLCg%3D)

#### How it works

```
/  # Split the string around occurrences of the substring.
,  # Get the length of the split array.
(  # Subtract 1.
```

Comment: Impressive.. But I have a small question, did you learn GolfScript just for code golf and solving code problems?

Comment: I did, but I use it occasionally for other tasks by now. Need an ASCII table? `golfscript <<< '127,32,-""+'` is faster than opening a web browser.

Comment: @Dennis `[win key] jqt [return] a. [return]` is even quicker ;)

Comment: @Synthetica: Well, it was just an example. But `jqt` sounds interesting. What is it?

Comment: @Dennis It's the standard J console that comes with J (it's one of those graphical consoles, like the `iPython QTConsole`)

Comment: @Synthetica: `jc <<< a.` seems to work as well. Learning J is still on my to-do list...

Comment: @Dennis Could be, I'm a gamer, so basically stuck on Windows. Also: learning GolfScript is still on mine as well.

Comment: @Synthetica I put it off for a good long while too. When I finally got around to it, it turns out there wasn't anything to learn. I do find often find myself writing out a phantom stack as I go, though

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript 32

Nothing really interesting here...

```js
(p=prompt)().split(p()).length-1
```

`split` main purpose is to create an array from a string using the delimiter in argument.

Comment: `split()` isn't part of "your language's API"?

Comment: it is but its purpose is not to count occurrences of a string... so where is the limit of authorized APIs ?

Comment: @Michael I apologize of being vague, this is acceptable.. I edited the question to rephrase to "you can't use your language's built-in function or method for counting occurences", so if it is not intended for the purpose of the question, you can use it...

Comment: @404NotFound Good to know ... this is my answer too then? :) ... (+1)

Comment: This is the only answer which doesn't assume that the vars have already been initialized, so you've got my upvote. If you assumed the vars were initialized like all the other answers, you would've gotten `a.split(b).length-1` 19. Maybe @svidgen should clarify initialization in the question.

Answer (score 2):

## J (7)

`No use of external libraries` Check! `, or your language's API.` Check...? I don't know what an language API is. `You have to implement it manually` Check!
`No file I/O` Check!
`No connecting with a server, website, et cetera` Check!

```
+/a E.b
```

How it works:

`E.` is `WindowedMatch`: the J Refsheet gives `'re' E. 'reread'` as example. This gives `1 0 1 0 0 0`. Then, the only thing left to do is simply adding this with `+/` (basically `sum`).

I don't think this counts as using `your language's built-in function or method for counting occurences`, but that's disputable.

EDIT:
Just to be clear:

```
   +/'aba'E.'ababa'
2
```

Comment: I thought `ababa` -> `aba` was to return 1?

Comment: @KyleKanos It was, but the author specifically said `@Synthetica Absolutley go for it!` when I asked him, so I suppose it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2.x - <strike>49 23</strike> 22 bytes

This is assuming variable input is okay. Both strings can be of any length.

Shortened @avall.

```python
a='s'
b='aaaabbbbsssffhd'
print~-len(b.split(a))
```

49 bytes version, counts every instance of the substring ('aba' is in 'ababa' twice).

```
a='s'
b='aaaabbbbsssffhd'
print sum(a==b[i:i+len(a)]for i in range(len(b)))
```

Comment: Worked with every test I put it in...

Comment: And language's API means you have to use your own function or method, not use the language's built-in way to do it (if it has one, I'm a C++ programmer;( )

Comment: Well the second one absolutely is language's own method for it. Also, the first one outputs 3 if `a='aa'` and b is the same. Is that okay?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: Also, it outputs 2 for the `a='aba'; b='ababa'` case.

Comment: @404NotFound If this is acceptable, I have a 7-byte J solution for you.

Comment: @Synthetica J is awesome, but it hurts my head. Python is clean, but takes so much space. I'm being torn apart by wanting both.

Comment: @TheRare I love both, I'm actually working on a library to unite both (J control structures and trains hurt my head, and I absolutely love Python's synthax/control structures and such).

Comment: @Synthetica PYG is nice, but I feel too dirty when using it.

Comment: @TheRare Oh, I'm not talking about PYG (rarely use it nowadays, only in chalenges that have me use `itertools`). I'm just working on some nice J bindings for Python, that are actually supposed to be suitable for an production environment.

Comment: @Synthetica I understood that, just came to my mind.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15012/discussion-between-therare-and-synthetica).

Comment: @Synthetica Absolutley go for it!

Comment: You can save one byte changing `print X-1` statement to `print~-X`

Comment: @avall Interesting. I always forget Python has unary operators.

Answer (score 1):

## C# - 73

```
//a = "aba";
//b = "ababa";

Console.Write(b.Split(new string[]{a},StringSplitOptions.None).Length-1);

// output = "1"
```

Comment: It's wrong! `aba` appears twice in ababa: `aba ba` `ab aba`.

Comment: @Runemoro "In a case of `ababa`, where it starts with `aba` and if you read the last 3 letters it's also `aba`, you only count one*" << In the rules..

Comment: Oh, didn't read...

Answer (score 0):

## Powershell 32

```
($args[0]-split$args[1]).count-1
```

Works like this:

```
PS C:\MyFolder> .\ocurrences.ps1 ababa aba
1
```

**Explanation:** Uses `-split` to separate the first argument by the second one, returns the size of the array resulting from the split (minus 1)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica <s>26</s>  23

Works like Dennis' algorithm, but wordier:

```
Length@StringCases[a,b]
```

Three chars shaved off by Szabolics.

Comment: `Length@StringCases[a,b]` is shorter.  This problem is not well specified because if we're not allowed to use `StringCount`, it's not clear whether any of the other builtin `String*` functions should be allowed either ... they're all based on the same underlying code.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot about `StringCases`. It was unclear to me what the OP meant by the language's API.

Comment: Using [the new composition operator in Mathematica 10](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Composition.html), we could even just write a function as `Length@*StringCases`.  This is shorter than `Length@StringCases[##]&` if we were to go for just writing a function but not actually apply it to `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

## Applescript, 106 bytes

Applescript is a fun, but silly language to golf in.

```
on run a
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to (a's item 1)
(count of (a's item 2)'s text items)-1
end
```

Run with `osascript`:

```
$ osascript instr.scpt s aaaabbbbsssffhd
3
$
```

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 66 Bytes

```
//s = "aba"
//t = "ababa"

Console.Write(t.Split(new[]{s},StringSplitOptions.None).Length-1);

//Output: 1
```

Comment: lol. That's basically my answer. Usually on this site, if you cant come up with something different than an existing answer, you can give hints to the existing answer on how to save a few extra bytes.

Comment: @malik Listen, I wasn't able to comment at that time. Otherwise I'd commented on your answer. I'm willing to take my answer down, if you want to.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't mind either way. I was just letting you know.

Answer (score 0):

## C <s>130</s> 120

Note: will probably crash if called with incorrect arguments.

```
r;main(int c,char**a){char*p=*++a,*q,*t;while(*p){for(q=a[1],t=p;*q&&*q==*t;q++)t++;*q?p++:(p=t,r++);}printf("%d\n",r);}
```

Ungolfed (kinda):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int result = 0;
    char *ptr = argv[1];
    while (*ptr) {
        char *tmp, *tmp2 = ptr;
        // str(n)cmp
        for (tmp = argv[2]; *tmp; tmp++, tmp2++)
            if (*tmp != *tmp2)
                break;
        if (*tmp) {
            ptr++;
        } else {
            result++;
            ptr += tmp;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n", result);
}
```

Old version with `strstr` and `strlen`: 103

```
l;main(int c,char**a){char*p=a[1];l=strlen(a[2]);while(c++,p>l)p=strstr(p,a[2])+l;printf("%d\n",c-5);}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Delphi XE3 (113)

Takes 2 strings, removes substring from string and substracts new length from old length followed by a division of the substring length.

```
function c(a,b:string):integer;begin c:=(Length(a)-Length(StringReplace(a,b,'',[rfReplaceAll])))div Length(b)end;
```

Testing:

> c('aaaabbbbsssffhd','s') = 3
> c('aaaabbbbsssffhd','a') = 4
> c('ababa','aba') = 1
> c('ababa','c') = 0

Answer (score 0):

## Lua (48)

So i thought I could just submit another answer, this time in lua.
Its very possible this could be improved a lot, im very new to this.

```
print((a.len(a)-a.len(a.gsub(a,b,"")))/b.len(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fortran 90: 101

Standard abuse of implicit typing, works for any length arrays `a` and `b`, though one should expect that `len(a) < len(b)`.

```
function i();i=0;k=len(trim(b))-1;do j=1,len(trim(a))-k;if(a(j:j+k)==b(1:1+k))i=i+1;enddo;endfunction
```

This function must be `contain`ed within a full program to work. `a` and `b` are received from stdin and can be entered either on the same line (either comma or space separated) or on different lines. Compile via `gfortran -o main main.f90` and execute as you would any other compiled program.

```
program main
   character(len=256)::a,b
   read*,a,b
   print*,i()
 contains
   function i()
     i=0
     k=len(trim(b))-1
     do j=1,len(trim(a))-k
        if(a(j:j+k)==b(1:1+k))i=i+1
     end do
   end function
end program main
```

Tests:

```
>ababa aba
2
```

I could make the above return 1 if I add 4 characters (`,k+1`) for the `do` loop

```
> aaaabbbbbsssffhd s
3
```

Answer (score 0):

### C++ 225

```
int n,k,m;
int main()
{
string s1,s2;
cin>>s1;
cin>>s2;
int x=s1.size(),y=s2.size();
if(x>=y)
{
for(int i=0;i<x;i++)
{
k=0,m=0;
for(int j=0;j<y;j++)
{
if(s2[j]==s1[i+m])
{
    k++,m++;
}
else break;
}
if(k==y)
{
n++;
i+=(y-1);
}
}
}
cout<<n<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Java (38)

```
System.out.print(a.split(b).length-1);
```

(The question did not require a complete program or function.)

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 25

```cobra
print a.split(b).length-1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [K/Kona](https://github.com/kevinlawler/kona) 6

```
+/y~'x
```

where `x` is the string and `y` the substring. `~` is the negate operator, with `'`, it is applied to every element in `x`; it will return `0` if it does not match and `1` if it does match. Since it is applied element-wise, the result of `y~'x` is a vector, the `+/` then sums the result giving the total number of occurrences.

Unfortunately, this method requires that `y` is only one character, otherwise we will be comparing a multi-character string to a single character string, resulting in a `length error`.